# Xamrin.Forms(Android) MessagingCenter Not Working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The created [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) is not working,
The value generated by the [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) variable is not moved to the other page.

my Code in CustomWebviewRenderer.cs

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
MessagingCenter.Send<CustomWebViewRenderer, Guid>(this, "Hi", guid);
```

MainActivity.cs

```
Guid guid;
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CustomWebViewRenderer, Guid>(this, "Hi",(arg1, arg2) =>
        {
            guid = arg2;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this is also buggy as hell so i just made a messager class in shared code that works well, and call it from Android.

Android code example:

```
Messager.Notify.TabBarClicked((int)tab.Position);
```

Shared code example:

```
public class Messager
    {

        public readonly static Messager Notify = new Messager();

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void TabBarClicked(int tag)
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "TabBarClicked", tag.ToString());
        }
        // something more...

    }
```

Adapt to your case.. 
Another buggy point is that i have much fails with messages if they have less or more than 1 arg parameter. And for me they also hate if parameters are not String type. No idea why, so just using workarounds..